Cannot Access Swagger through Ngrok
My swagger page runs succesfully on my lcoalhost URL http://localhost:52438/swagger/ui/index.
But when I try to access the web application through ngrok link https://879d-2407-aa80-116-f1aa-fdc2-d8f4-cff5-a595.ngrok-free.app/swagger/ui/index
I am initiating ngrok link via this command ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 52438
I am getting error:
Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.


It depends on how you are running swagger. My guess is the ajax requests are going to localhost instead of the ngrok url and are thus failing. You may try with https://pinggy.io/ and ask in the discord channel. Usually the support is better.
